# Android How to draw a smooth line between two points like(A,B) following your finger from point A to B

Tags: java, android

Like this. It has two points and when you go from `A` point to `B`, then the line should be created.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you create a like with its (x1, y1) grounded to a specific location and then set its other point (x2, y2) to their respective mouse variable / finger. Like so: line(10, 10, mouseX, mouseY);

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for questions about programming, but we will not do all the work for you. Please show us what you have tried, what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal and vertical line
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
and get points on Motion_MOVE event